# Generate new columns as a combination of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has several components of an identifier in the columns and a value associated with the identifier in another column. I want to be able to create n columns such that each of the column is the identifying parameter.

```
            foo    Type      ID     Index    Value  
25090        x       A        0       0     23272000
25090        x       A        0       0     23272000
25091        x       A        1       0     22896000
25092        x       B        0       1     20048000
25093        y       A        0       0     19760000
25092        y       B        0       1     20823342
```

I want to make it such that there are n columns of `Type_ID_Index` groupings (which I can get by groupby) and each of the columns has the respective value. I want the value to be associated with foo.

i.e.

```
           foo          A_0_0     A_1_0     B_0_1      
25090        x         23272000  22896000  20048000
25090        x         23272000  22896000  20048000
25091        x         23272000  22896000  20048000
25092        x         23272000  22896000  20048000
25093        y         19760000  21568000  20823342
25092        y         19760000  21568000  20823342
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your example data

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
      foo  bar Type  ID  Index     Value

25090   x    9    A   0      0  23272000
25090   x    5    A   0      0  23272000
25091   x    3    A   1      0  22896000
25092   x    3    B   0      1  20048000
25093   y    6    A   0      0  19760000
25092   y    4    B   0      1  20823342
```

Concatenate each row's identifer by applying `join` row-wise.

```
In [4]: identifier = df[['Type', 'ID', 'Index']].apply(
             lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, x)), axis=1)
```

Make a Series from your Value column, and index it by the identifer and foo.

```
In [5]: v = df['Value']

In [6]: v.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['foo'], identifier])

In [7]: v
Out[7]: 
foo       
x    A_0_0    23272000
     A_0_0    23272000
     A_1_0    22896000
     B_0_1    20048000
y    A_0_0    19760000
     B_0_1    20823342
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Unstack it, and join it to the original DataFrame on 'foo'.

```
In [8]: df[['foo', 'bar']].join(v.drop_duplicates().unstack(), on='foo')
Out[8]: 
      foo  bar     A_0_0     A_1_0     B_0_1

25090   x    9  23272000  22896000  20048000
25090   x    5  23272000  22896000  20048000
25091   x    3  23272000  22896000  20048000
25092   x    3  23272000  22896000  20048000
25093   y    6  19760000       NaN  20823342
25092   y    4  19760000       NaN  20823342
```

Notice that I dropped the duplicates in `v` before unstacking it. This is essential. If you have different values for the same idenitifer anywhere in your dataset, you will run into trouble.

Minor points: Your example output has a row (25094) that is missing from your example input. Also, the NaNs in my output make sense: no value is specified by A_1_0 when foo='y'.

Comment: _If you have different values for the same idenitifer anywhere in your dataset, you will run into trouble._ Yup. My measurements will likely be noisy so this will be a problem. What is an elegant way to average them?

Comment: I think I got this. Here is what I did:  
    v = v.groupby(v.index).mean()
    v.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(v.index)