# Combining values from an arbitrary number of pandas columns into a new column — a 'join' in the not-SQL sense

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm trying to do what's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952815/combine-values-from-arbitrary-number-of-columns-into-new-one), but it's not the case that only one of my columns is populated, and I want to have a delimiter.

The code I'd like to replace (with something that will take an arbitrary number of k's) is:

```
    raw_df["all ks"] = raw_df["k1"].fillna("") + "/" + \
                       raw_df["k2"].fillna("") + "/" + \
                       raw_df["k3"].fillna("") + "/" + \
                       raw_df["k4"].fillna("")
```

I wondered if [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026216/pandas-combining-values-in-multiple-columns-to-create-a-new-column) could be somehow responsive, but I'm hoping for something simpler.

Thanks for any helpful suggestions. Searching the web has been frustrating because I'm trying to do a join (in the pythonic sense) and most search results relate to joining columns in the database sense (including as adapted in pandas).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.cat.html) string method to concatenate the string values. With this method you can specify the delimiter and what the `NaN` values should be replaced with.

For example, here's a DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', np.nan, 'x'], 
                       'b': ['y', 'y', np.nan], 
                       'c': ['z', 'z', np.nan]})
     a    b    c
0    x    y    z
1  NaN    y    z
2    x  NaN  NaN
```

Then starting with column `a` and passing in the remaining columns using a list comprehension:

```
>>> df['a'].str.cat(others=[df[col] for col in df.columns[1:]], 
                    sep='/', na_rep='')
0    x/y/z
1     /y/z
2      x//
```

Comment: @BobHaffner: Thanks! Also good to see a solution using `apply`; it could be handy for implementing more exotic concatenation functions.

Comment: try to use str.cat over apply whenever you can. feels a gazillion times faster.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I came up.  It uses Apply() and a function.  Not as concise as I hoped, but it works with an arbitrary number of Ks.  Maybe someone will come up with something better

Generating a dataframe

```
 d = {'k1' : [np.nan,'a','b'], 'k2' : ['c', np.nan, 'c'], 'k3' : ['r','t',np.nan], 'k4': [np.nan,'t','e']}
    raw_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    raw_df

    k1   k2   k3   k4
0   Nan  c    r    Nan
1   a    Nan  t    t
2   b    c    Nan  e
```

define a function

```
def concatKs(s):
    allK = ''
    for k in s:
        if k is not np.nan:            
            allK += k + '/'
        else:
            allK += '' + '/'
    return allK
```

then the apply() and passing our function

```
raw_df['all ks'] =  raw_df.apply(concatKs, axis=1)
raw_df

    k1  k2  k3  k4  all ks
0   NaN c   r   NaN /c/r//
1   a   NaN t   t   a//t/t/
2   b   c   NaN e   b/c//e/
```